# On pushforward functor and freeness of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Given an $R$-module $M$ and a ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to R$, let $\phi^* M$ be the $R$-module whose underlying abelian group is the same as $M$ but the $R$-linear structure is given by $r\cdot m=\phi(r)m, \forall r\in R, m \in \phi^* M$.

Now let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be, moreover, local and $\phi:R\to R$ be a ring homomorphism such that $\phi^n(\mathfrak m)\subseteq \mathfrak m^n$ and $(\phi^n)^*R$ is a finitely generated $R$-module for all $n\geq 1$ (here, $\phi^n$ denotes $n$-fold composition). If $(\phi^e)^* R$ is a free $R$-module for some $e>0$, then is $(\phi^s)^* R$ a free $R$-module for infinitely many $s>0$ ?

Comment: This is true if $R$ is a ring of prime characteristic $p>0$ and $\phi=F$ is the Frobenius endomorphism, Kunz showed that for a Noetherian ring $R$, $F^e_*(R)$ being flat for any or all $e$ is equivalent to $F_*(R)$ being flat, which are equivalent to $R$ being a regular local ring (then you use that flatness = freeness over a local ring). I'm sure this is a motivation for your question already.

Comment: In general, look at "Homology over local rings" by Avramov-Iyengar-Miller, Theorem 13.3. Your condition for holding for any $n$ is equivalent to regularity, since a module being flat implies it has finite flat dimension. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functor $f^*$ has both adjoints, so it preserves all limits and colimits, so in particular if $(\phi^s)^*(R)$ is a free module with generators indexed by $I$, then $(\phi^{ks})^*(R)$ is free with generators indexed by $I^k$.

Comment: Does this imply if $(\phi^s)^*(R)$ is free for some $s>1$ then $\phi^*(R)$ is free?

Comment: @walkar No, but it does imply that if $(\phi^s)^*R$ is free for a single $s$, then it is free for infinitely many $s$.

Comment: I see. Your answer doesn't depend on $\phi$ being a contraction ($\phi(\mathfrak{m}^n)\subset \mathfrak{m}^n$) or $R$ being local, does it?

Comment: It does not, $f$ can be an arbitrary morphism of arbitrary rings.

Comment: can you please provide a reference for why $f^*$ has both adjoints ?

Comment: @Alex https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300531/adjoints-of-scalar-extension-and-scalar-coextension In this question, your functor is denoted $f_*$.